# Does the play store link change when uploading a new apk version

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-play, qr-code

When an apk gets uploaded it generates a link for the app to the play store. I want to distribute the link and the QR code in a printable paper. If I upload a new version of the apk, does the link change and render the previous printed paper useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to application in Google Play is created from package name of your *.apk file and it never changes after update. Moreover you should never change your package name. When you use link like this:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps
```

You can be sure that it will be permanent. You can read also very old article about things that cannot change in android application.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot :)